# Multiple hero widget with gridview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, hero

I was trying to create a UI design for food app. therefore I tried multiple container box using hero widget but couldn't get the result due to an error. the error is:

**ErrorSummary('There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.'),
ErrorDescription(
'Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), '
'each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.\n'
'In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: $tag',
),**

please help how to make multiple hero widget with different key tag. and went through many tutorials but couldn't get the idea well. if a detailed demo would be fine thank you.

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that two containers don't have the same tag and in your Gridview every container has its **particular and unique tag**.

Every **Hero** widget has one **tag** parameter.
You should use the same tag for one source container and its destination hero by pass it to the next widget, like this sample:

```
 return GridView.builder(
    reverse: true,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
     return Hero(
        tag:'$index',
        child: Container(child:  
                  MyDestinationContainer(
                      heroTag: '$index'  
                  ),
        ),
     );
    },
    itemCount: 10,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  );
```

For more information see [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/hero-animations#basic-structure-of-a-hero-animation).

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("Text"),
                );
              },
            )
```